# Error when using a NDK built Library which depend on another one in a Unity project

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, android-ndk, shared-libraries, .so

I want to create a native C++ program and use it on Android and I learned to do so using the Android NDK. I've even created a test plugin (lib*.so ) which worked perfectly. But when I created a plugin which depend on the first one (meaning another shared library created with the NDK) and used it in a Unity project, it didn't work. I've got this error :

```
    E/Unity   ( 4719): Unable to find MyLib
I/Unity   ( 4719): DllNotFoundException: MyLib
I/Unity   ( 4719):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) TestDLLScript:Foo ()
I/Unity   ( 4719):   at TestDLLScript.Start () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
I/Unity   ( 4719):
I/Unity   ( 4719): (Filename:  Line: -1)
I/Unity   ( 4719):
```

Is this a problem from Unity or is there some procedure that I need to follow to make this work?

Also here is my plugin make file, even though I don't think that the problem came from it (since it built without any error or warning) :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := TestDLL
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libs/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libTestDLL.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/source
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := MyLib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += MyLibrary.cpp
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += TestDLL
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `lib*.so` must be built for all ABIs, not only one. So take a look, for what ABI you've built your library, then be sure, your application is built for the same ABI.

There's a big chance you have no your library in final apk file. Take a look inside apk.

Comment: My library is built for armeabi-v7a and x86, the two ABIs that Unity support. And my two libraries are in the final apk in "libs" folder.